# List of time series characteristics

Tags: time-series, references

Is there a source (paper, book, presentation, lecture) that gives an overview of all or most of the different attributes by which we can characterise time series signals along with definitions and examples (e.g., (non-)cyclic seasonality, trend, (dis-)continuous, stationary, and so on)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the book [Forecasting: Principles and Practise](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) as a good starting point.